# ActivePresentation in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

In VBA, we have `ActivePresentation`. I want to know how can we do the same in VB.NET.

I have the following code

```
Dim oApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim oPres As PowerPoint.Presentation = oApp.ActivePresentation
```

My question is how do we declare or use ActivePresentation in VB.NET.

Can anyone help me how we can use `ActivePresentation` in VB.NET.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: My question is actually how do we declare or use ActivePresentation in VB.NET

Comment: Although you edited out the fact that you received a NullReferenceException, that is in fact your problem. See the proposed duplicate.

Comment: You have already correctly declared the ActivePresentation. If, after solving the NullReferenceException. you want a tutorial on how to use ActicePresentation, that would be too broad a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to declare `oApp` as `New` Application, to create a new instance of PowerPoint.

This is required because your code is not ran "inside" PowerPoint like it would be with VBA.

After that you need to open a presentation (or create a new one) which then is available via `ActivePresentation`.

```
Dim oApp As New PowerPoint.Application
oApp.Presentations.Open("C:\test.pptx")
Dim oPres As PowerPoint.Presentation = oApp.ActivePresentation
```

You can also open multiple presentations at the same time, they can be addressed via name:

```
Dim oPres As PowerPoint.Presentation = oApp.Presentations("test.pptx")
```

...or index (beginning with 1):

```
Dim oPres As PowerPoint.Presentation = oApp.Presentations(1)
```

Comment: Exactly, what I was looking for. Many thanks. It worked like a charm. Thanks for the explanation, I was not able to find for active presentation in vb.net.